# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) - Python

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to make a connection with an external websocket.
I copied the message my browser is sending to this websocket but unfortunately python is giving me this error.
I hope someone can figure it out..

```
from websocket import create_connection

link = "wss://sbapi.sbtech.com/bet777/sportscontent/sportsbook/v1/Websocket?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NjA4MTU3OTUsImlzcyI6ImFnZW50X0JldDc3NyIsIlNpdGVJZCI6NzIsIklzQW5vbnltb3VzIjp0cnVlLCJTZXNzaW9uSWQiOiI4NmJjNmMzOS0wMmNkLTQyZDctOTg5OC03MjBhZGFhYmM5OGEiLCJuYmYiOjE2NjA4MDg1OTUsImlhdCI6MTY2MDgwODU5NX0.f9T1bPsuMNYETXUhy-K9rmdmdQ_p2lQIvJmFGsveZ2H2DeA6_-tEE_83oFgDqVihuFHBdTe69rXir2rgoKjWcJxMR49cD7fixpWhJ0s4JFfc2VQIscNaVzGO-q7EAPZlWpYJe91WOXM-kcaPPtRYpcZkjcy7_D6vuEZKdlRGD5kA0TKt7DGSsA1dNgdZ1Hvw0JwDMxcNKJ9LFnJjz4v2mFMwozVL79T6mQSTQwR4HFiid4vH6STIzZ_dejxp86PDe68mj_e7Vko4eGX3vl9ihYyqUXeVePI0Yqac9fysiHCrrYJ2Cs4Z4_fCi1CrW3Ft2VIXQkJ_6Ls8vD9crmtreA&locale=nl"

message_to_send = {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
                   "params": {"eventState": "Mixed", "eventTypes": ["Fixture", "AggregateFixture"], "ids": ["40815"],
                              "regionIds": ["20"], "pagination": {"top": 100, "skip": 0}, "marketTypeRequests": [
                           {"sportIds": 1,
                            "marketTypeIds": ["1_39", "2_39", "3_39", "1_169", "1707", "1_0", "2_0", "3_0"],
                            "statement": "Include"}]}, "method": "GetEventsByLeagueId",
                   "meta": {"blockId": "eventsWrapper-Center_LeagueViewResponsiveBlock_17829"},
                   "id": "e0621fd8-e7b0-4458-8aaf-d4a83b6e90a9"}

ws = create_connection(link)
ws.send(message_to_send)
result = ws.recv()
print(result)
ws.close()
```

Is giving me TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
Thanks a lot already for the effort!

Comment: Can you post the full traceback (formatted as code) please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.